# Best way to synch AD with IBM Tivoli access manager

Tags: azure-active-directory, tivoli, directory-server

We have an AD in MS AZURE cloud and IBM Access Manager in our in house datacenter.
I like to know what is the best way to synch users between these 2 system?
But that I mean, user will be added to AD in cloud. at the same time I want the same user to be added in Tivoli Access Manager. I am looking for the best approach

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft Azure Active Directory Adapter is an interface between a managed resource and the IBM® Security Identity server. The Microsoft Azure Active Directory (Azure Active Directory Adapter) uses the Tivoli® Directory Integrator functions to facilitate communication between the IBM Security Identity server and Microsoft Azure Active Directory (Azure Active Directory).

Adapters can be installed on the managed resource. The IBM Security Identity server manages access to the resource by using the security system. Adapters function as trusted virtual administrators on the target operating system. The adapter creates, suspends, restores user accounts, and other functions that administrators run manually. The adapter runs as a service, independently of whether you are logged on to the IBM Security Identity server.

The adapter automates several administrative and management tasks.
You can use the adapter to automate the following tasks:

- Create, modify, suspend, restore, change password, and delete a user.
- Create, modify, and delete group.
- Reconcile user and user attributes.
- Reconcile group and group attributes.

Reference - [IBM Security Identity Manager: Microsoft Azure Active Directory Adapter Installation and Configuration Guide](ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/security/products/isim/adapters/6.0/azure_60_book.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for the info, This was before I knew about SCIM. Do you think SCIM is a better solution instead of TDI since both Azure and ISAM support it?

Comment: Yes, I also checked SCIM but was not sure if ISAM supported it. If yes, then go with SCIM.

Comment: Is there an SCIM endpoint for Azure AD to provision users into Azure AD from other identity providers